# Running WL in a Jupyter Notebook in VSCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have Wolfram Engine (and wolframscript) installed. I want to create Jupyter Notebooks that run WL in VSCode. I don't have Jupyter installed on my computer since I have it as an extension in VSCode. My research has led me to believe that I need to make VSCode/Jupyter find some "Wolfram Kernel". I can't seem to find any proper resources/documentation on this.

Comment: You may want to check out this link: [https://nicoguaro.github.io/posts/wolfram_jupyter/](https://nicoguaro.github.io/posts/wolfram_jupyter/)

Comment: Link provides instructions for JupyterLab not VSCode. If there was supposed to be a way to deduce the VSCode instructions from the JupyterLab instructions, it might not be obvious or easy for the less technically-experienced in this matter like myself, hence why I am asking for proper instructions for setting up the Wolfram Kernel for VSCode.